# Remove cellpadding ,cellspacing and border from table

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I tried to send simple newsletter using oscommerce platform and the content is simple table with few images. Before i send the preview look good (no `cellspacing` or `cellpadding`)

Preview:

[image]

But after I receive and open using gmail :

[image]

you can see the table is different; I mean the white border.

Here is code for generate table and content for newsletter .

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><img alt="" src="http://www.sfbeautyskin.com/uploads/image/Newsletter/Newsletter.jpg" style="width: 950px; height: 1187px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="http://www.sfbeautyskin.com/images//banners/Promotion_Dec_Xmas.jpg"><img alt="" src="http://www.sfbeautyskin.com/uploads/image/Newsletter2.jpg" style="width: 950px; height: 114px;" /></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="http://www.sfbeautyskin.com/index.php"><img alt="" src="http://www.sfbeautyskin.com/uploads/image/Newsletter3.jpg" style="width: 950px; height: 158px;" /></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="http://www.sfbeautyskin.com/contact_us.php"><img alt="" src="http://www.sfbeautyskin.com/uploads/image/Newsletter4.jpg" style="width: 950px; height: 440px;" /></a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The question is how to completely remove border property.

Comment: There are many tutorials which suggests `display:block` if you search on google as keyword -- "**gmail image spacing issue**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with emails before.  If I remember correctly, I fixed it by making the image (or try 'a' tag) inside the td use `display: block`.

Try something like this:

```
<td><img alt="" style="display: block;" src="http://www.sfbeautyskin.com/uploads/image/Newsletter/Newsletter.jpg" style="width: 950px; height: 1187px;" /></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="line-height:0"` for each td

```
<td style="line-height:0"><img ... /></td>
```

Comment: I'm not able to adjust the img tags since they're dynamically created in my situation.  So this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On each of your `tr`, `td` and `img` elements, add `style="margin:0;padding:0;"`

Or just delete your table all together. They seem to serve no purpose.

Comment: While it's "cool" to use CSS, tables make it easier to create well ordered, well defined columns and rows. When you need cols and rows in a few mins, use a table, when you wanna spend the entire day scripting, do it in CSS.

Comment: @JasonCaldwell It's not a matter of cool or not. The table literally serves no purpose here. He can replace the table with nothing, not css, not div, not etc. There is only one column here.

Comment: @Grumpy Apologies, I read the "+1 to deleting unnecessary table" and assumed it was another CSS cultist trying to push CSS over a table. CSS groupies annoy me, looks like I posted without reading the initial question. Wink.

Answer (score 0):

**Now Define your** `img` tag `vertical-align:top`

```
<img src="some.jpg" style="vertical-align:top;" />
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/NKeG2Z4D)***

### --------

Answer (score 0):

Check the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/tuD6L/12/

```
margin: -5px 0;
```